# MySQL workbench SSH connection error [Bad authentication type(allowed_types=['publickey'])]

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have issue regarding SSH connection with my server. When i try to connect it results into error:"Bad authentication type(allowed_types=['publickey'])"
Thanks

Comment: What do I do if I'm on a Mac ? Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your username and public key this can cause problem.
Attach the private key file with extension .ppk
Also verify your connection with putty.
Also check for the restriction on server.

Comment: Hi, These all things are checked already but having same problem again and again

Comment: hi, can you please attach screen shots?

Answer (score 7):

You need to ensure that your private key is in openssh format. With puttygen you can export as Openssh. This worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me. I opened PuTTY Gen and loaded my key. Then I exported it as open SSH by clicking on the "Conversions" menu in PuTTy and selecting "Export SSH Key".

Answer (score 0):

FYI, my company uses a Yubikey and so the SSH part can be a bit mysterious. However, walking through a shell login with the yubikey yinit command, to ssh to IP (no password needed here), and finally to connecting mysql (still shell), I attempted to MySQL Workbench a few times with my different passwords to no avail.

Finally, I noticed the "SSH Key File" field and looked up where my .ssh file was -- /Users/myProfile/.ssh/
Set the "id_rsa.pub" file as it and voila!

Everything worked.